# Condition rendering of photo using map

Tags: reactjs, image, map-function

I'm trying to render a specific photo based on the input from a user. I map over the users information and get all the fields right except the img field where I try to add a conditional statement.

This is currently my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faXmark } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { newList } from './SearchBar'
// import { carsAvailable } from '../assets/data/cars'
import Nissan from '../assets/images/nissan.png'
import Mini from '../assets/images/mini.png'


function Modal() {

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    let imgUrl;

    const carUrl =() => {
        if (newList.car === 'Nissan Juke'){
        imgUrl=Nissan;
        }
        else{
            imgUrl=Mini;
        }
    }


    

    return (
        <>
            <button
                className="bg-pink-500 text-white active:bg-pink-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                type="button"
                onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}
            >
                Open regular modal
            </button>
            {showModal ? (
                <>
                    <div className="justify-center items-center flex h-full fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                        <div className="relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-3xl">
                            <div className="border-0 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none">
                                <div className="flex items-start justify-between p-5 border-b border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-t">
                                    <h3 className="text-3xl font-semibold">
                                        Nearly there..
                                    </h3>
                                    <button
                                        className="p-1 ml-auto bg-transparent border-0 text-black float-right text-3xl leading-none font-semibold outline-none focus:outline-none"
                                        onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                                    >
                                        <span className="">
                                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faXmark} />
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>                                
                                <div className="relative p-6 flex-auto">{
                                    newList.map((data)=>
                                    <>
                                    
                                    <h4> Please fill in the below form and submit to send us your enquiry</h4>
                                    <img src={carUrl[imgUrl]} />
                                    <h1>Car: {data.car}</h1>
                                    <h2>Pick up desination: {data.pickup}</h2>
                                    <h3>Pick up time and date: {data.pickupDate} {data.pickupTime}</h3>
                                    <h2>Drop off desination: {data.dropoff}</h2>
                                    <h3>Drop off time and date: {data.dropDate} {data.dropTime}</h3>
                                    </>)

                                }
                                </div>
                                {/* <form>
                                    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-5">
                                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                                            <input type="text" className='bg-gray-300' required />
                                            <label >First name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                                            <input type="text" className='bg-gray-300' required />
                                            <label>Last name</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                                        <input type="email" className='bg-gray-300 w-96' required />
                                        <label >Email address</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-6">
                                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                                            <input type="number" className='bg-gray-300' required />
                                            <label>Age</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                                            <input type="tel" className='bg-gray-300' required />
                                            <label>Phone number</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form> */}
                                <div className="flex items-center justify-end p-6 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b">
                                    <button
                                        className="bg-emerald-500 text-white active:bg-emerald-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                                        type="button"
                                        onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                                    >
                                        Submit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
                </>
            ) : null}
        </>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

but none of the images are rendering. I am locating the images from the right place but nothing is showing

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you expecting this to do?:

```
carUrl[imgUrl]
```

`carUrl` is *a function*.  So you'd invoke it like any other function:

```
carUrl(imgUrl)
```

Though let's also look at that function:

```
const carUrl =() => {
    if (newList.car === 'Nissan Juke'){
        imgUrl=Nissan;
    }else{
        imgUrl=Mini;
    }
}
```

This function:

1. Doesn't accept any arguments, but you're trying to pass it one.
2. Doesn't return anything, but you're trying to use its return value.

You can fix the first issue by not passing it anything:

```
<img src={carUrl()} />
```

And you can fix the second by returning a value:

```
const carUrl =() => {
    if (newList.car === 'Nissan Juke'){
        return Nissan;
    }else{
        return Mini;
    }
}
```

After which the `imgUrl` variable is no longer used and can be removed entirely.

---

Though on further inspection, this also makes no sense:

```
newList.car === 'Nissan Juke'
```

Is `newList` an object or an array?  The name implies an array, but this usage assumes it's an object.  Then later this usage assumes it's an array:

```
newList.map((data, car)=>
```

It can't be both, so which is it?  Let's assume it's *supposed to be* an array, in which case an array *doesn't have* a property called `car`.  Did you mean to pass the `car` value from within the `.map()` callback?  That would look more like this:

```
const carUrl =(car) => {
    if (car === 'Nissan Juke'){
        return Nissan;
    }else{
        return Mini;
    }
}
```

And you'd pass it that argument:

```
<img src={carUrl(car)} />
```

Though let's also look at what `car` *is*:

```
newList.map((data, car)=>
```

The second argument to the `.map()` callback is *the index* in the array.  Array indexes are *numbers*, so it will *never* equal the value `'Nissan Juke'`.  Did you mean to pass `data` instead?:

```
<img src={carUrl(data)} />
```

Or a property on `data`?:

```
<img src={carUrl(data.car)} />
```

Ultimately, understanding your data model and what values you need to use is up to you.  But overall:

1. Calling a function is done with parentheses, not square brackets
2. A value needed by a function should be passed to a function
3. A function should return a value if its return value is needed